# How to get image to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/r73b14y5/3/

script works fine but cant get the image to slide back to the original location if another link is not clicked.

at the moment the image stays where ever it last hovered over, instead of only staying at a link if the new link was clicked. and sliding back to the original link if nothing is clicked.

Also whats the best way to delay the hover state so as the mouse flys over the element quickly it doesnt activate. hover intent.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bblock1" style="height:100%;">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMaxS">
    <div class='tabbed_content'>
        <div class='tabs'>
            <div class='moving_bg'>&nbsp;</div>
            <span class='tab_item tab_item_color'>OVERVIEW</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>THE SCIENCE</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>ORDER</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>REPLACEMENT FILTERS</span>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bblock3" style="height:100%;">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMaxS">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

** key part of Script:**

```
$(".tab_item").mouseover(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.parent().find(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: $this.position()['left']
            }, { duration: 300 });
    });
```

**rest of script**

```
 var TabbedContent = {
        current: {i:null, obj:null},
        init: function() {
            $(".tab_item").click(function() {
            $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color");
            $(this).addClass("tab_item_color");
                var $this = $(this);
                TabbedContent.slideContent($this);
            });
            TabbedContent.current.i = 0;
            TabbedContent.current.obj = $(".tabslider li").eq(0);
        },
        slideContent: function($obj) {
            var $container = $obj.closest(".tabbed_content"),        
                $contentContainer = $('.bodymainMaxS'),
                $tabslider = $contentContainer.find(".tabslider");
            var i = $obj.index() - 1;
            var $lis = $tabslider.find("li");
            $new = $lis.eq(i);
            if(i === TabbedContent.current.i) {
                return;
            }
            $lis.hide().filter($new.add(TabbedContent.current.obj)).show();
            var margin_1 = (i > TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
            var margin_2 = (i < TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
            $tabslider.stop().css({
                marginLeft: margin_1 + "px"
            }).animate({
                marginLeft: margin_2 + "px"
            }, 400);
            TabbedContent.current.i = i;
            TabbedContent.current.obj = $new;
        }
    }
    TabbedContent.init();
```

Comment: which browser are you using??

Comment: im using firefox. code not working in your browser?

Comment: code is working fine and i cannot detect the issue you have mentioned

Comment: the image should slide back to where it was if a link was not clicked

Comment: at the moment the image stays where ever it last hovered over instead of only staying at a new link if the new link was clicked. and sliding back to the original link if nothing is clicked.

Comment: When I open you fiddle link, then if I move my mouse over your headings the image move along with my mouse, so what I get from your question is that you want to stop image on heading which you select or click, isn't it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122013/discussion-between-muhammad-irfan-and-david).

Comment: Thats correct it follows the mouse, but when the mouse is out of the element and nothing was clicked then it should slide back to its original position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete JS fixed replace whole javascript with this one ([you can test here with JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fb5b5ud/) )

removed TabbedContent because that was not being used (if you need that you can always copy from your question)

```
var isTabSelected = false;
var lastSelectedTabLeftPos;
$(".tab_item").mouseover(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.parent().find(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: $this.position()['left']
            }, { duration: 300 });
    });
    $( ".tab_item" ).mouseout(function() {
    if(isTabSelected){

    $(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: ""+lastSelectedTabLeftPos
            }, { duration: 300 });
    }else
    {
    $(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: "0"
            }, { duration: 300 });
    }
        });
$(".tab_item").click(function() {
isTabSelected = true;
var $this = $(this);
lastSelectedTabLeftPos = $this.position()['left'];
});
```

Comment: Please check the JSfiddle link in my answer to test the new JS code I have provided :)